# How do I adjust Unity build settings to ensure game compatibility across Android devices?

Tags: unity-game-engine, hardware, build-settings, system-requirements

I just finished makeing an android 2D game (low graphics) but when I test it in my tab it shows - "Your device does not match the hardware requirement for this application."
It's my first game that I am testing on android and I don't know how to set the build setting so it is compatable for all devices. Please help me.<3

I thought that it is something of the API problem so i tried the game on a mobile with the same API level (android 5.1.1) but it worked correctly. Then I tried to build a new empty game to test on the tab and the game showed the same problem so I figured out that I have not set the right build setting and I have no idea how to set it right. I also download the sdk again but the problem still arives.

Comment: Maybe you need to add OpenGL ES 2.0 to your settings. https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/android-requirements-and-compatibility.html

Comment: In addition to the other advice here make sure if you use any non standard shaders that they have fallbacks in case the device doesn't support those shader functions: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/SL-Fallback.html

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you’re having trouble with the build settings for your Android game. One possible solution could be to check the Minimum API Level in the Player Settings for Android. Make sure that it is set to a value that is supported by your tablet.

Another possible issue could be related to the hardware requirements of your game. You can try lowering the graphics quality or reducing the complexity of your game to see if that helps.

Comment: I don't think graphics is the problem here because I tried to make another apk from an empty scene but it also didn't work so it is more likely to be a problem from the build setting but Thanks.